# Custom listener with interface

Tags: java, android

I am trying to understand better how to create a custom listener with a simple example but I don't know how to start the interface so that it is not null:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListenerButton{

    TextView helloToOther;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        helloToOther = findViewById(R.id.helloWorldToOtherActivity);

        helloToOther.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ButtonActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClickButton(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Estoy en la primera activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is the second activity:

```
    public class ButtonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnInterface;
    ListenerButton listenerButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_button);

        btnInterface = findViewById(R.id.button_activity__btn__button_interface);
        setUpButtonInterface();
    }

    private void setUpButtonInterface() {
        btnInterface.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listenerButton.onClickButton(v);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And there's the interface:

```
    public interface ListenerButton {

    void onClickButton(View view);
}
```

Basically I get a null pointer exception on the second activity because the interface is null, but I don't fall right now as I can start it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason you are getting a null pointer exception is because you haven't assigned anything to variable `listenerButton` and therefor it is in fact null!!
you don't need a new interface for that you just need to do this:

```
    public class ButtonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnInterface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_button);

        btnInterface = findViewById(R.id.button_activity__btn__button_interface);
        setUpButtonInterface();
    }

    private void setUpButtonInterface() {
        btnInterface.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do whatever you want to do when button is clicked!
            }
        });
    }
}
```

if you want to define whatever you want to do when button is clicked you need a class and not an interface:

```
public class ButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do whatever you want to do when button is clicked!
            }
}
```

and then in your activity do this:

```
    public class ButtonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnInterface;
    ListenerButton listenerButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_button);
        listenerButton = new ButtonListener();
        btnInterface = findViewById(R.id.button_activity__btn__button_interface);
        setUpButtonInterface();
    }

    private void setUpButtonInterface() {
        btnInterface.setOnClickListener(listenerButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if I want what that button does to be defined in the other class? For example, send you a text that is in the other class.

Comment: I kind of guessed that was, what you were going for. so I updated the answer for that. can you check if my new update matches your request?

Comment: And there's no way to do it with an interface? I know I've passed data from one activity to another with interface. Or I've used the button on a RecyclerView in the view adapter...

Comment: the thing is that you can not put the implementation in an interface! it's only a list of your function (in simplest term possible!)

Comment: this link might help you grasp the concept:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interfaces-in-java/

Comment: @Isaac did it fix your problem? I'm happy to help if more help is needed :)

Comment: One last thing: there are times when I have had an application with a Recycler View that is filled through the call to a Retrofit service, and if I wanted to pass data by clicking somewhere in the row, I did it through an interface, isn't this something similar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206379/discussion-between-saeed-foroughi-and-isaac).

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file:

> MyListener.java:

```
public interface MyListener {
    // you can define any parameter as per your requirement
    public void callback(View view, String result);
}
```

In your activity, implement the interface:

> MyActivity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyListener {
   @override        
   public void onCreate(){
        MyButton m = new MyButton(this);
   }

    // method is invoked when MyButton is clicked
    @override
    public void callback(View view, String result) {   
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

In your custom class, invoke the interface when needed:

> MyButton.java:

```
public class MyButton {
    MyListener ml;

    // constructor
    MyButton(MyListener ml) {
        //Setting the listener
        this.ml = ml;
    }

    public void MyLogicToIntimateOthers() {
        //Invoke the interface
        ml.callback(this, "success");
    }
}
```